# Change formatting of Currecncy Field of a sharepoint list using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, client-side-rendering

Can I change formatting of a Currency field using PowerShell

for example

in swedish regional setting currency field shows **100.000 kr** (.dot as separator)

but I need to customize it's format to show as **100 000 kr** (space as separator)

Can I do that?
How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this requirement by using client side rendering(CSR) easily. Here 'Currency' is a currency type field.

```
(function () {
var overrideCurrentContext = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Fields = {
    'Currency': { 'View': Currency }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);

function Currency(ctx) {
   var modifiedCurrency =ctx.CurrentItem.Currency.split(",").join(" ");
   return   modifiedCurrency
} 
})();
```

**Before :** 
[image]

**After :** 
[image]

Steps to add JS Link :

- Save the below code to projectCode.js and upload to site assets of site collection/subsite
- Go to the list view and go to the edit page by appending "toolpaneview=2".
- Edit the webpart and open the 'miscellaneous' section.
  In the JSLink text box refer the JS file. If you have uploaded to the site collection's site assets, use `~sitecollection/siteassets/projectcode.js` . If you have uploaded it to subsite's site assets use `~site/siteassets/projectcode.js`

Comment: This should be enough to get the OP going, but I think you copy/pasted from a previous answer.  You're replacing semi-colon with line breaks, instead of `.` with a space.

Comment: Thanks @wjervis . After testing it out, pasted an old revision of the code which I started out with. Have fixed it now.